# How can i call expire_action from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have 3 models, Clients, has many Projects, has many Jobs.

When you create a client or a project there are ActiveRecord Callbacks to create a default project or default job. Since this is done from the model level the cache does not expire.

I am using action caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [sweeper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers) to observe the models and expire the cache appropriately.

Comment: where do you put the observer file? lib? models?

Comment: create a sweepers folder in /app and name the script inside `<your_model>_sweeper.rb`.